# Is there anyway to define/run a macro on specific condition in C++?

Tags: c++, macros

Is there anyway to define/run a macro on specific condition in C++?

My application takes some parameters on running, say `./test -l`

I want to define a macro if -l is provided as a parameter, so I tried:

```
if  (strcmp(argv [2],"-l")==0)
        #define LOOPBACK
```

but it's wrong. My application is always defining `LOOPBACK`!!

Comment: You understand that macros are evaluated at **compile-time**, not runtime, right?

Comment: The problem is that the preprocessor is run in a separate [phase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases) and is basically separate from C++. It's also done completely during build, and does not do anything during runtime.

Comment: Why this love of macros? They are only useful in limited circumstances and that is very few in c++

Comment: sometimes u need to use ur code 4 different purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All preprocessor directives (e.g: `#include`, `#define`, ...) are performed/ evaluated by the preprocessor, which runs before the compiler. So the macro you're defining is defined without knowing about the `if(...)` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Preprocessor macros perform text substitution, and the output of the preprocessor is then compiled as code.

That means, by definition, that macros can only be defined, redefined, undefined or expanded at (strictly speaking, before) compile time.   There is no way for a macro to have a different expansion based on runtime data.

It also means that macros don't honour any rules of scope.

Which is why your LOOPBACK macro is always defined - the expansion is unrelated to the `if` statement.